# Python RE. excluding some results

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to RE and I'm trying to take song lyrics and isolate the verse titles, the backing vocals, and main vocals:

Here's an example of some lyrics:

```
[Intro]
D.A. got that dope!

[Chorus: Travis Scott]
Ice water, turned Atlantic (Freeze)
Nightcrawlin' in the Phantom (Skrrt, Skrrt)...
```

The verse titles include the square brackets and any words between them. They can be successfully isolated with

```
r'\[{1}.*?\]{1}'
```

The backing vocals are similar to the verse titles, but between (). They've been  successfully isolated with:

```
r'\({1}.*?\){1}'
```

For the main vocals, I've used

```
r'\S+'
```

which does isolate the main_vocals, but also the verse titles and backing vocals. I cannot figure out how to isolate only the main vocals with simple REs.

Here's a python script that gets the output I desire, but I'd like to do it with REs (as a learning exercise) and cannot figure it out through documentation.

```
import re

file = 'D:/lyrics.txt'
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    lyrics = f.read()

def find_spans(pattern, string):
    pattern = re.compile(pattern)
    return [match.span() for match in pattern.finditer(string)]

verses = find_spans(r'\[{1}.*?\]{1}', lyrics)
backing_vocals = find_spans(r'\({1}.*?\){1}', lyrics)
main_vocals = find_spans(r'\S+', lyrics)

exclude = verses
exclude.extend(backing_vocals)

not_main_vocals = []
for span in exclude:
    start, stop = span
    not_main_vocals.extend(list(range(start, stop)))

main_vocals_temp = []
for span in main_vocals:
    append = True
    start, stop = span
    for i in range(start, stop):
        if i in not_main_vocals: 
            append = False
            continue
    if append == True: 
        main_vocals_temp.append(span)
main_vocals = main_vocals_temp
```

Comment: Note that in `x{1}`, the `{1}` is useless. `x` already looks for one and only one character

Comment: Also, generally speaking, it will be quite hard to find a regex that easily extracts your `main_vocals` at once. The way it works is if you managed to extract the `verses` and `backing_vocals` with regexes, simply use those regexes to replace with empty strings in `main_vocals`. Going back to my previous comment, it means that all your `{1}` can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3xfXx1/1):

```
pattern = r'(?P<Verse>\[[^\]]+])|(?P<Backing>\([^\)]+\))|(?P<Lyrics>[^\[\(]+)'
```

You can use `re.finditer` to isolate the groups.

```
breakdown = {k: [] for k in ('Verse', 'Backing', 'Lyrics')}
for p in pattern.finditer(song):
    for key, item in p.groupdict().items():
        if item: breakdown[key].append(item)
```

Result:

```
{
  'Verse': 
    [
      '[Intro]', 
      '[Chorus: Travis Scott]'
    ], 
  'Backing': 
    [
      '(Freeze)', 
      '(Skrrt, Skrrt)'
    ], 
  'Lyrics': 
    [
      '\nD.A. got that dope!\n\n', 
      '\nIce water, turned Atlantic ', 
      "\nNightcrawlin' in the Phantom ", 
      '...'
    ]
}
```

To elaborate a bit further on the pattern, it's using the named groups to separate the three distinct groups.  Using `[^\]+]` and similar just means to find everything that is *not* `]` (and likewise when `\)` means everything *not* `)`).  In the Lyrics part we exclude anything that starts with `[` and `(`.  The [link to the demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3xfXx1/1/) would explain the components in more details if you need.

If you don't care for the newlines in the main lyrics, use `(?P<Lyrics>[^\[\(\n]+)` (which excludes the `\n`) to turn your Lyrics without newlines:

```
'Lyrics': [
  'D.A. got that dope!', 
  'Ice water, turned Atlantic ',
  "Nightcrawlin' in the Phantom ", 
  '...'
]
```

Comment: python is quite amazing, I should learn it some day.. I've been warned though :P

Comment: Python is very handy indeed.  Though in this case half the glory is from the regex engine itself.  Not sure what you mean by "warned", I have nothing but love for Python. :)

Comment: means i've been told many times it's great :) and yeah regexes are great too, once you went past the gibberish aspect

Answer (score 1):

You could search for the text between close-brackets and open-brackets, using regex groups.  If you have a single group (sub-pattern inside round-brackets) in your regex, re.findall will just return the contents of those brackets.

For example, `"\[(.*?)\]"` would find you just the section labels, not including the square brackets (since they're outside the group).

The regex `"\)(.*?)\("` would find just the last line ("\nNightcrawlin' in the Phantom ").
Similarly, we could find the first line with `"\](.*?)\["`.

Combining the two types of brackets into a character class, the (significantly messier looking) regex `"[\]\)](.*?)[\[\(]"` captures all of the lyrics.

It will miss lines that don't have brackets before or after them (ie. a the very start before [Intro] if there are any, or at the end if there are no backing vocals afterwards).  A possible workaround is to prepend a "]" character and append a "[" character to the end to force a match to start/end at the end of the string.  Note we need to add the DOTALL option to make sure the wildcard "." will match the newline character "\n"

```
import re

lyrics = """[Intro]
D.A. got that dope!

[Chorus: Travis Scott]
Ice water, turned Atlantic (Freeze)
Nightcrawlin' in the Phantom (Skrrt, Skrrt)..."""


matches = re.findall(r"[\]\)](.*?)[\[\(]", "]" + lyrics + "[", re.DOTALL)
main_vocals = '\n'.join(matches)
```